# Quicksort in C, with hoare partition

Tags: c, algorithm, quicksort

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int w, q, p, r;
int tab[100];

void main ()
{
    int i;
    srand(time(0));
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i += 1)
    {
        tab[i]=rand()%100;
    }
    display(tab);
    r = 37;
    quicksnort(tab, 0, r-1);
    display(tab);
}


int display (int tab[])
{
    int i;
    printf("\n Your numbers : \n");
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i += 1)
    {
        printf(" %d", tab[i]);
    }
}


int quicksnort(int tab[], int m, int n)
{

    if (p<r)
    {
        q = partition(tab, m, n);
        quicksnort(tab, m, q-1);
        quicksnort(tab, q+1, n);
    }
}

int partition(int tab[], int p, int r)
{
    int x, i, j, part;
    x = tab[p];
    i = p-1;
    j = r+1;
    do
    {
        do
        {
            j = j-1;    
        } while (tab[j]<=x && j>=0); 
        do
        {
            i = i+1;    
        } while (tab[i]>=x && i<=0);
        if (i<j)
        {
            part = tab[i];
            tab[i]=tab[j];
            tab[j]=part;
        }
        else
        {
            return j;
        }
    } while (1);
}
```

Hi, i have problem with the code above. It will compile but when i run it, it stops and display some sort of alert of "core dump".
It's based on hoare version of quicksort, to be axact on that peudocode http://screenshooter.net/5359896/jyuogoj 
I've tried everything to make it work, i think that it might have something to do with pointers. I think that because i'm not sure how they work in C.

(Ok, i know that they are pointing at cell and stuff, but i'm getting lost with pointers with pointers, or pointers used in functions, or table of pointers to function, and things like that. I honestly don't know where to look to get more specific info about that)

But maybe solution is simpler than that.

Comment: have you tried to use a debugger on it?

Comment: Is this homework? If not, consider using the standard C function `qsort()`.

Comment: btw, it would be nice if you format your code better

Comment: I like the misspelling: `quicksnort` :)

Answer (score 2):

Run it in a debugger and see.  Compile with `cc -g` so it's compatible with a debugger.  Google `dbx cheatsheet` to learn basic commands.  It will take you less time to learn basic debugger use AND isolate your error than it took you to write your post, which is why it's a good tool to invest time into learning.

Comment: I'm working on your solution. But to tell you the truth, i'm not sure of it. I'm using gcc and i have virtual xubuntu. Did you mean "gcc -g" ?

Comment: Whichever compiler you're using - so yes probably gcc.  The important part is the -g.

Answer (score 1):

There are some mistakes in your code...

p,r,q aren't defined before you use them.

I'm surprised you didn't get any warnings when you compiled.

I think what is happening is you are infinitely recursing because of invalid values (p,r,q.. etc) and your OS finally runs out of memory to give your program.

Also, please format your code better so it is easier to read. Use a nested structure and 8 spaces or a Tab for every sub clause or statement.

Comment: I am sorry, one of them ment to be named partition, but i mistakenly changed it to quicksnort. I did that only while posting it here, so when is changed properly to partition, it does not solve the problem.
(I did that because originaly i named it in another language, and to your comfort i wanted to rename it).

However, the problem still exists.

Comment: Yea, sorry I should have realized that. I edited my answer. Make sure all your variables are initialized before they are used. I'm positive it is a core dump due to running out of memory. Also, if you want a debugger with a GUI and you are on a Unix/Solaris machine, see if you have `dbxtool` installed. It comes with Solaris / Sun Studio if you want to go download it.

Comment: Do mean giving them value like "int p=0;" ? Because i did that for all variables, and the problem remains the same. Also, getting that debugger is in progress.

Comment: I'm on xubuntu linux. Unfortunately, it would take me about forever (this means about 6 hours, if i manage full speed),to download Sun Studio, because i have relatively quite slow internet connection. So, it would be great if you have some smaller debugger to recommend, or i'll have to wait (or miraculously somehow i'll find debugger on my computer).

Comment: well you should already have `dbx`. Also check out `gdb`, or `mdb` depending on what you need it for. What is the exact error message you get when the program crashes?

Comment: Check out the answer by ugoren. That might have something to do with your problem.

Comment: Hurray ! I have gdb! We all shall praise torvalds ;) 
But now, i debugged it, the almighty debugger said:
"Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x08048679 in partition (tab=0x804a080, p=0, r=36) at moc.c:64
64         tab[i]=tab[j];"
Although it's not double-rainbow, i don't know what exactly does it mean. What wisdom comes with it ?

Comment: Print out i and j in that loop. Particularly above the tab[i] = tab[j] line. One of those must be out of bounds to get a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

I think the loop in `partition`, which sets `i`, decrements it instead of incrementing.

You want to move `i` and `j` in opposite directions, but you decrement them both.

Comment: yup, that's one mistake, but it's not it. It is still not working.